# Create Variable When Class is a Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a parent class Visit with child classes `InpatientVisit`, `ClinicVisit`, etc.  **Ultimately I want to create a list of visits, where the type could be the parent or any child**.  So far I can do this:

```
Type visitType = null;
        Visit visit = new Visit();
        switch (typeOfVisit)
        {
            case VisitType.All:
                visit = new Visit();
                break;
            case VisitType.Inpatient:
                visit = new InpatientVisit();
                break;
            case VisitType.Clinic:
                visit = new ClinicVisit();
                break;
            case VisitType.Emergency:
                visit = new EmergencyVisit();
                break;
            case VisitType.DaySurgery:
                visit = new DaySurgeryVisit();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        visitType = visit.GetType();
```

This where I get stuck.  Eventually I want to do something like this:

```
for (int rowCounter = 0; rowCounter < data.Rows.Count; rowCounter++)
        {
            Visit thisVisit = new Visit(data, rowCounter);
            this.Add(thisVisit);
        }
```

**I need a replacement for `Visit thisVisit = new Visit(data, rowCounter);**

The appropriate constructors either currently or will exist.

Comment: Unrelated comment; rather than assigning `new Visit` just before the switch, only to assign something else, leave `visit` unassigned and put `new Visit` in the `default` block so that it is definitely assigned after the `switch` block.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. are you saying you don't want Visit to have overload ctors?

Comment: You've stated what you *don't* want to do, but not what you *do* want to do.  Could you perhaps post some code (that you know currently won't work) to give us an idea of what you might like the calling syntax to look like.

Comment: I get the feeling you're trying to create an instance of a class depending on the type you've found in the first part?  It seems to me that you'd be best using something like `Activator.CreateInstance()`?  Otherwise, you could have a Factory method using generics?

Comment: Thak you for the one answer and three comments so far.  Two people thought I was unclear so I edited the post and put some stuff in bold font.  Activator.CreateInstance() looks promising. I'd never heard of it before.

Comment: have you seen Joel Etherton answer? Why can't you use that approach?

Comment: I can use Joel's approach.  In fact it's the one I'm working on.  I was going to post an answer once I was sure I had one but the question was closed.  Oh well, at least I got my answer first

Answer (score 2):

Create an interface that they all implement:

```
public interface IVisit
{
    // put any common function signatures here 
}
```

The your list can be typed as a `List<IVisit>` and at that point it won't matter which visit type is being stored. Then you can create a factory method whose responsibility is to know which type of IVisit to return

```
public static IVisit GetVisitInstance(VisitType typeToCreate)
{
     switch(typeToCreate)
     {
        case VisitType.All:
           return new Visit();

        case VisitType.Inpatient:
            return new InpatientVisit();

        case VisitType.Clinic:
            return new ClinicVisit();

        case VisitType.Emergency:
            return new EmergencyVisit();

        case VisitType.DaySurgery:
            return new DaySurgeryVisit();

        default:
            return null;
     }
}
```

This is not the most scalable solution, and if you search around you will find much better (re: scalable) factory implementations that do this. But given what you already have this should be a fairly simple method to do it.

Comment: Since `Visit` is the base type of all of them, you don't need the `IVisit` interface, and the static method can live on `Visit` itself.

Comment: @Bobson: Yes, both are true, but my thinking is that by suggesting the interface it might lead to a more generic/scalable solution on his end beyond what we're seeing here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a class of type `Visit`, and insert in this class objects of classes: `Visit, InpatientVisit, linicVisit, EmergencyVisit`, then the best approach would be to use interfaces as `@Joel Etherton` pointed out.
But you can create a list of parent class and just add derived classes to a list.
Let's say you have the following structure:

```
 class Visit
    {
        public string VisitName { get; set; }
    }
    class ImpatientVisit : Visit
    {
        public int ImpatientProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you can create list of visits like this:

```
            List<Visit> listOfVisits = new List<Visit>();

            var regularVisit = new Visit();
            regularVisit.VisitName = "regular";

            var impatientVisit = new ImpatientVisit();
            impatientVisit.VisitName = "impatient";
            impatientVisit.ImpatientProperty = 3;

            listOfVisits.Add(regularVisit);
            listOfVisits.Add(impatientVisit);
```

Then you can iterate through list like this:

```
            foreach (var visit in listOfVisits)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(visit.VisitName);
            }
```

This will print out

```
regular
patient
```

But you cannot access `ImpatientVisit` properties without casting.
So you can do something like this:

```
            foreach (var visit in listOfVisits)
            {
                var impVisit = visit as ImpatientVisit;
                if (impVisit != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(impVisit.ImpatientProperty + " "+ impVisit.VisitName);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(visit.VisitName);
                }
            }
```

This will print out

```
regular
3 impatient
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Activator class, you can create a factory method to do this:

```
public static T CreateVisit<T>(DataSet ds, int row) where T : IVisit, new()
{
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { ds, row });
}
```

Note: All classes would need to implement an interface, IVisit

This would then be called from your code like this:

```
InpatientVisit inpatientVisit = CreateVisit<Inpatient>(data, row);
```